# How to parse a JSON array into a POJO

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON structure like this:

```
{
    "text" : "MVA/Transport. Greater Hume (Hume Hwy, Holbrook, NSW 2644) at 7 Mar 2017 03:58 #NSWRFS #MVATransport",
    "user" : {
        "id" : "4721717942",
        "name" : "NSW Fire Updates"
    },
    "lang" : "en",
    "coordinates" : {
        "coordinates" : [147.273696, -35.785469],
        "type" : "Point"
    },
    "created_at" : "Mon Mar 06 17:29:31 +0000 2017"
}
```

I'm having trouble parsing the `coordinates` array inside the `coordinates` object.

```
public class ParsingTweet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        assert args != null & args.length > 0;
        List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("tweets.json"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                tweets.add(mapper.readValue(line, Tweet.class));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tweets);
    }

}
```

where `coordinates` prints as:

```
coordinates = ClassPojo [type = Point, coordinates = [Ljava.lang.Double;@1810399e]]
```

instead of:

```
coordinates = ClassPojo [type = Point, coordinates = [147.273696, -35.785469]]
```

---

Here are my POJOs:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Tweet {

    private String text;
    private String created_at;
    private User user;
    private Coordinates coordinates;

    public Tweet(){
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public String getCreated_at()
    {
        return created_at;
    }
    public void setCreated_at(String created_at)
    {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
    public Coordinates getCoordinates()
    {
        return coordinates;
    }
    public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates)
    {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[text = "+text+", created_at = "+created_at+", user = "+user+", coordinates = "+coordinates+"]";
    }
}



public class Coordinates {
    private String type;
    private String[] coordinates;
    public String getType ()
    {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType (String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String[] getCoordinates()
    {
        return coordinates;
    }
    public void setCoordinates (String[] coordinates)
    {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [type = "+type+", coordinates = "+coordinates+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your parsing code?

Comment: i just added them

Comment: and the Tweet class?

Comment: i just added them again

Comment: i think the solution is pretty simple, its just i cant seem to find it

Comment: is it because the type declaration is String instead of Double?

Comment: Maybe the question is how to print an array? (see `Arrays#toString`)

Comment: @RC wait so the code is actually fine and correct?

Comment: if the question is how to make the `toString` print `coordinates = [147.273696, -35.785469]` then the answer is using `+ Arrays.toString(coordinates) +` in `Coordinates` but what you ask is really unclear

Comment: @Kutam I'll edit your question to make it clear if that's ok with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try changing from `String[]` to `List<String>` in `Coordinate`.

It looks like it's reading it as a `Double[]`? Though I don't understand why since your `Coordinate` class has a `String[]` field.

---

Consider if you had JSON array with 1 value or more than 2 values - the parser will happily parse it into a Java List or array even though they aren't valid coordinates.

Rather than parsing to `double[]`, `String[]` or `List<String>`, it'd be better if you had a `Coordinate` POJO that has a `double latitude` and `double longitude` as properties. You could do this with your JSON parsing library or you can consider this as a first conversion parse of API models, and then you convert once more to your domain models.

Comment: well shouldnt it be a double? because the result should be "coordinates = [147.273696, -35.785469]"

Comment: I'm unsure how the parsing library you're using (Jackson?) works and whether it can infer the type correctly.

Comment: The method here works. can you tell me the advantage of using this method instead of using Arrays.toString()? or they are just the same? just different convention?

Comment: I would rather deal with `List` than arrays unless I'm _trying_ to optimise for something. I don't know why it tried to convert to `Double[]` since the type was `String[]` in Coordinate. In your case, I would try to create a custom class that holds Coordinate (with lat and long as `double`) and not use `List<String>` nor `String[]`.

Comment: you are actually correct. My instructor just told me probably change it to double. Can you show me how i would go about this??

Comment: and cant i just use for List<Double>?

Comment: probably you can, try it

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an array... so you would want to correctly do that

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return  + Coordinates.class.getSimpleName() 
        + " [type = " + type 
        + ", coordinates = " + Arrays.toString(coordinates)
        + "]";
}
```